# Replacing element from a specific position at a file in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, file-handling

I am facing a logic building problem.

Let's suppose I have following data in txt file:

```
David The Angel 20-04-2019
Bilal Learning how to read 20-04-2019
Sarah The subtitle art of not giving the <expletive deleted> 20-04-2019
```

Now I want to change the date of second line from 20-04-2019 to 25-04-2019

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you show what you have so far?

Comment: You need to read the file, change the line you want and write it back. You can read and write 1 line at a time if you want. No need to have the entire file in memory.

Answer (score 1):

In order to replace the bytes from positions `S` (inclusive) to `E` (exclusive) in the file with a byte array of length `L` there are 3 possible cases to consider:

- `E - S == L`: The easy case, file size doesn't change. [seek](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp) to `S` and write the `L` bytes.

  ```
  // overwriting 4 bytes with 4 bytes
  oooS---Eooo
  oooLLLLEooo
  ```
- `E - S < L`: Writing more into the file, size increases.  As a first step "move" every byte starting with `E` by `L - (E - S)` "further to the back".  This makes room to write `L` bytes to `S` without overwriting the byte which was at `E` (and the following bytes).  Once this "moving" is done, seek to `S` and write the `L` bytes.

  ```
  // replacing 4 bytes with 6 bytes
  oooS---Eooo
  oooS---??Eooo
  oooLLLLLLEooo
  ```
- `E - S > L`: Writing less into the file, size decreases. As a first step "move" every byte starting with `E` by `(E - S) - L` "further to the front" of the file.  This reduces the room between `S` and the new position of the byte which was at `E` to be exactly `L` bytes long.  Now the more tricky part: Truncate the file (remember, size decreased!).  C++17 filesystem TS has [`resize_file`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/resize_file) for this, otherwise use a) some library (boost?) b) platform dependent calls (`truncate` on POSIX systems). Finally, write the `L` bytes to `S`.

  ```
  // replacing 4 bytes with 2 bytes
  oooS---Eooo
  oooS-Eooo??
  oooS-Eooo
  oooLLEooo
  ```